# What does Top 1% mentioned by ATC refer to?

Tags: air-traffic-control, phraseology

I have watched Live ATC tons of time. But I still don't know which airline is called "Top 1%". Ex: Delta 81 right Bravo right Kilo give way to company A380 and follow the Top 1%".

Just wanna know what "Top 1%" means. Or that is only for JFK?

Comment: Do you have a link to the audio?

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17083/62)

Answer (score 36):

I'm guessing you're referring to a clip such as [this one](https://youtu.be/JNUL-jX8IeE?t=1m46s). JFK ground is just being a bit informal and fun (as you can tell from the rest of the clip) with their instructions. Although it isn't mentioned, the controller is probably referring to a business jet flight, such as [ExecJet](http://flightaware.com/live/fleet/EJA).

The "top 1%" refers to a ranking based on income, specifically those not in [the lower 99%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_are_the_99%25). The controller is basically telling them to follow the rich people in their fancy private jet. JustSid found [another video](https://youtu.be/_0qLshYMKys?t=1m25s) where the controller explains it as "someone richer than both you and me."

Comment: Snarky! Listening to a few other clips of that same atc makes me wonder if it's such a good idea to let Howard Stern take over as ground controller.

Comment: @TomMcW it seems to be tradition at JFK and BOS to have snarky ground controllers. :)

Comment: Actually, it is mentioned. One of the pilot readbacks is "follow the Gulfstream," so your guess is correct. :)

Comment: Here is [another "video"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0qLshYMKys) which explains Top 1% as `"Someone richer than both you and me"`. So, yep, spot on indeed.

Comment: @JustSid thanks, included a link to that one.

Comment: Oh yeah. Even thought I cant found the exact video I am saying but this link is also okay. :))