# Where are "standard taxi" instructions published?

Tags: air-traffic-control, faa, taxiing

Example: at KATL (Atlanta), the ground control sometimes gives taxi instructions as "standard taxi"; Where is that defined?

> Delta 2732 27-Right Lima Charlie "Standard Taxi."

In that case, from a south ramp, the aircraft is noticed taxiing on Lima to 27R at intersection LC.

The question is, how did the pilot know that "standard taxi" meant going on taxiway Lima? Where are "standard taxi" instructions defined/published?

Comment: Please don't create a new question for this. You can edit your original question to add details, so it can be re-opened.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Where can I find airport taxi instruction “code names”?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14018/14897)

Answer (score 3):

[You can find a nice article on standard taxi routes here.](https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/regulations/what-you-should-know-about-standard-taxi-routes/) They are included in the NOTAMS, or on Jepp charts if you have access to them. The full standard for publishing them [can be found here.](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7210.61.pdf)

This is what they look like:

[image]

(source: own image)

As ymb1 points out in the comments [you can access them here as well](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ntap/sw19000.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It brings me back to my original question though. I don't have access to Jepp charts so I'm relying on Notices to Airmen only. In ForeFlight the current release of Notices to Airmen (Feb. 27, 2020) doesn't have any notices for Southeast United States. So, since Atlanta is in the Southeast U.S., there are no Standard Taxi Routes published for Atlanta. I was just wondering if anybody knew of anywhere else they might be published other than Jepp Charts or Notices to Airmen. I'm guessing they're not. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: @Kent: For ATL it's explained in [the post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/14019/14897) I linked; it's a LOA between the airport and the carriers.